# Shadow under ActionBar when using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock. On Android 3.0+, there's a subtle shadow under the ActionBar. But  not on older Androids.

The problem is, that the shadow set in `android:windowContentOverlay` appears at the top of the Activity Window. And on older Androids, ActionBar is part of the Window. So the shadow overlays the top of the ActionBar, instead of overlaying the content under ActionBar.

Is there a way to solve this, without manually inserting the shadow to every Activity's layout?

Comment: Either you can alter ActionBarSherlock layout files, or Create a custom activity class with shadow added to layout (FrameLayout with shadow drawable), and extend other activities from that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the second. I feel pretty stupid, this seems obvious now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wingman hinted in the comments, I overrided `setContentView(...)` in my base `Activity` like this:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResId) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, null);
    setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    int wrapContent = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int matchParent = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent));

    View shadow = new View(this);
    shadow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_bar_shadow);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent,
            wrapContent);
    shadow.setLayoutParams(params);

    RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(this);
    container.addView(view);
    container.addView(shadow);

    super.setContentView(container);
}
```